# How to find the common elements of two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

For a program that I am writing for fun (one that finds the Greatest Common Denominator and the Lowest Common Multiple); I've come across some difficulty.

I have two arrays that contain 14 numbers. To find the Lowest Common Multiple of all the numbers, I need to compare every element in each array. So far I've got this test:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
    {
        if(array[i] == arr[j])
        {
            tesst[i] = array[i];
        }
    }   
}
```

The thing is, there are endless amounts of things that could go wrong with:
`tesst[i] = array[i]`

Can anyone help me sort out my little algorithm?

Comment: Do you want to compare the contents of the arrays and put the matching elements into a 3rd container?

Comment: If I knew how to do it without failure, yes.

Comment: Homeworks are called programs for fun from now on... I see :)

Comment: @user1074152 See my answer below to do it without failure.

Comment: I wish. I'm not old enough to go to college/University yet.

It's only to get things like algorithms going well in my head... A mini Project Euler :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort each of your input arrays, then get the intersection using [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/).

Comment: Thank you. This should do nicely!

Answer (score 1):

- If the ordering matters, you will find

  - [`std::mismatch`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/mismatch.html)
  - [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lexicographical_compare.html)

  quite useful
- Otherwise, look at

  - [`std::sort`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) (!! important) followed by
  - [`std::set_intersection`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_intersection.html)

Comment: Thank you. The answer has already come up, but mismatch and lexicographical look really fun!

Comment: Yes, *this* is really funny...:)

Comment: @RomanB.: come on, you were young once! Oh drat, maybe you still are. Well, toying is fun!